# How to calculate a GPU's max resolution

Tags: multiple-monitors, gpu, nvidia-quadro

I'm planning on running 8x 2560x1440 displays, ideally at 60hz.

For example, say a card says it can do:

- 4x displays @ 4096x2160 @ 60hz
- 8x displays @ 4096x2160 @ 30hz
- 8x displays @ 1920x1080 @ 60hz

if I apply the following math to the above assumptions:

- 4x displays @ 4096x2160 is a total of **35,389,440** pixels
- 8x displays @ 2560x1440 is a total of **29,491,200** pixels

It would seem that everything comes down to the number of pixels that need to be handled. According to my numbers, my setup would be *less* pixels than the example card at 60hz. But, I don't know enough about GPU internals to understand how everything works and whether my math and assumptions are just nonsense.

Is my GPU max resolution calculation correct?

Comment: I *think* it should run fine at 60Hz, though I have a question: What single card supports 8 monitors? Because if you have to run 2 cards anyway, wouldn't that off-load some of the work between themselves? However, based on Nvidia's FAQ site, only maximum of 2 monitors are supported through SLI (additional monitors can be added with a card that's not the same as those in SLI, which is still a maximum of 6 monitors). May I ask what your setup is? Very curious.

Comment: @HatsuneVocaloidMiku NVS 810. Moderators made me edit that out of the question.

Comment: If we take "pixels @ some Hz" as the total throughput a card can handle then yes, it should run your setup at 60Hz. Though instead of taking advice from a stranger on the internet, wouldn't it be better to ask the manufacturer themselves?

Comment: @HatsuneVocaloidMiku At the time of this question, i had already made the purchase. I didn't notice the constraints until later.

Comment: You can still ask to get more information, or pretend to be a customer of interest. I've found the latter to be way more responsive in some companies.